# Line chart Dot update issue in D3

Tags: charts, d3.js, line

I am facing an issue while updating the dots on line chart. if total number of data remains same, it works but if number of data changes, i am not able to update the circle and tool tip.I know there is isssue with enter and update section. Here is the Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cYrUy/)

```
    blueCircles.data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.qName); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
                    .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .transition()
        .duration(750);
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated

Comment: Did you see e.g. [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) that teaches you how to handle selections? It looks like in your code you're only handling the `.enter()` selection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if you see my code, i have made the selecttion in blueCircles .its not changing the existing value.

Comment: As I've said, this is because you're only handling the `.enter()` selection and not the update selection.

Comment: Can you please provide me some code to understand, i m totally missing the point

Comment: Did you have a look at the tutorial? Everything is explained in detail there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late answer. 
But if someone searches for a solution this might help.

The problem was this line:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").transition();
```

After I cleaned it out, I got rid of some strange errors and was able to add circles to the svg.

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/noo8k17n/